# How to use a string with redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I'm sure this is a bone-headed question, so apologies in advance. I want to use a string with my redirect_to, like this:

```
class AppStoreController < ApplicationController

  def get_app
    .
    .
    .
    redirect_path_string = "address_book_path"
    redirect_to redirect_path_string
  end

end
```

(The redirect_path_string will be constructed using available variables in the controller, but I wanted to abstract out that detail for this question.)

When I do this, I get "The connection was reset" in my browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this - you can redirect with a string, but it would be helpful if you could give us just one, fully composed string (with variables inserted) that is failing.

Comment: @normalocity - I followed Yosep's advice and it worked like a charm. But, to respond to your post, my fully-composed string, in fact, was "address_book_path". Apparently, as Yosep pointed out, I needed the string to be a fully-qualified URL and not a named path. Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply a fully qualified URL in order to use a string against redirect_to. Rails utilize a convention to generate a URL from *_path, in this case 'address_book_path'. The following is some examples of what you can do with redirect_to. For more info, go to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to

```
redirect_to :action => "show", :id => 5
redirect_to post
redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_to articles_url
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Constructing my string as a fully-qualified URL does exactly the trick. Brilliant.